# Apply css to target class using reference class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to target `col-sm-5 col-md-5` class for apply custom css:

```
<div class="container extra-info">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wasn't your question about using `target`? Why did you change it?

Comment: i have only above coding format can not add external id so using class i need solution

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Thats how i will select the first `.col-sm-5`

```css
.extra-info:first-child > .row > .col-sm-5 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container extra-info">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
     test
     </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="container extra-info">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5">
     test
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks friend  its works for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an ID to apply target. So add an `id` first:

```
<div class="container extra-info">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5" id="target">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now you can use the pseudo selector:

```css
#target::target {
  background: #f00;
}
```

You just need to navigate to: `/path/to/file#target`.

If you just want to target that element, it's as simple as:

- Adding a new `class`.
- Adding a new `id`.

So, for either, try to do the following:

**Solution using `class`**

```
<div class="container extra-info">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 target">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And use the CSS:

```css
.target {
  background: #f00;
}
```

**Solution using `id`**

```
<div class="container extra-info">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5" id="target">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And use the CSS:

```css
#target {
  background: #f00;
}
```